# Выборка по порядку даты из двух таблиц MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Есть две таблицы

```
1 act
id | name   |  data
1  | Ivan   |  2015-01-01
2  | Petr   |  2015-01-03

2 serv
id  |  name  |  data
1   | Serge  |  2015-01-02
2   |  John  |  2015-01-04
```

как мне составить выборку, чтобы распределялось по датам, но из двух таблиц. так чтобы шли данные из `data=2015-01-01`, потом `data=2015-01-02`, потом `data=2015-01-03`, `data=2015-01-04`, и ещё вопрос - должны ли в таблицах совпадать названия ячеек?
Если нельзя mySQl, тогда подскажите как можно обработать эти данные через `php` так, что бы получилось как я просил.

Comment: select * from act union select * from serve order by data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> должны ли в таблицах совпадать названия ячеек?

не обязательно. достаточно их перечислить в нужном порядке.

например:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca203f/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table act  (id int, name text, data date);
create table serv (name1 text, data1 date, id1 int);

insert into act values
   (1, 'иван', '2015-01-01')
  ,(2, 'пётр', '2015-01-03')
;

insert into serv (id1, name1, data1) values
   (1, 'сергей', '2015-01-02')
  ,(2, 'джонни', '2015-01-04')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id, name, data from act
union
select id1, name1, data1 from serv
order by data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca203f/2/0)**:

```
| id |   name |                      data |
|----|--------|---------------------------|
|  1 |   иван | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|  1 | сергей | January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
|  2 |   пётр | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
|  2 | джонни | January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Спасибо вы дали наиболее полный ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, data from (
    select id, field1 AS name, field2 AS data from act union
    select id, field3 AS name, field4 AS data from serv
) order by data;
```