# обработка двух разных таблиц MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

есть две таблицы

```
1 act
id | name   |  data
1  | Ivan   |  2015-01-01
2  | Petr   |  2015-01-03

2 serv
id  |  name  |  data
1   | Serge  |  2015-01-02
2   |  John  |  2015-01-04
```

я делаю выборку из этих двух таблиц  так  что  они распределяются по датам,  двух таблиц.Получаю я это таким запросом.

```
select id, name, data from act
union
select id1, name1, data1 from serv
order by data
```

вопрос в следуюшем мне всеже надо понимать из какой таблицы я получил ну к примеры дату. Такое можно получить метадом MySQl ну или PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так добавьте эту информацию

```
select 'Это из таблицы 1', id, name, data from act
union
select 'А это- таблицы 2', id1, name1, data1 from serv
order by data
```

Только насколько я помню, данные должны быть настолько **одного типа**, что даже длины строк должны совпадать. Так что, проще поставить число - 1 или 2

Comment: а названия столбцов должны совподать ?

Comment: я на всяк случай делаю `as commonFieldName`. Но, по хорошему, надо почитать

Answer (score 2):

дополнил свой ответ на ваш [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445615/178576) столбцом «таблица».

повторяю ответ, данный уже там: имена столбцов не обязательно должны совпадать.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca203f/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table act  (id int, name text, data date);
create table serv (name1 text, data1 date, id1 int);

insert into act values
   (1, 'иван', '2015-01-01')
  ,(2, 'пётр', '2015-01-03')
;

insert into serv (id1, name1, data1) values
   (1, 'сергей', '2015-01-02')
  ,(2, 'джонни', '2015-01-04')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 'act' as `таблица`, id, name, data from act
union
select 'serv', id1, name1, data1 from serv
order by data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca203f/5/0)**:

```
| таблица | id |   name |                      data |
|---------|----|--------|---------------------------|
|     act |  1 |   иван | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|    serv |  1 | сергей | January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
|     act |  2 |   пётр | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
|    serv |  2 | джонни | January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
```